# How do I program the GNOME Clock Calendar with Python?

Tags: gnome, python, application-development, calendar

I want to develop a little application and I want to add events to the calendar of the Gnome panel clock. How does it work? Is there a D-Bus Interface I can use? Or can I directly access the evolution-data-server?

Answer (score 3):

The [Evolution-python](https://live.gnome.org/Conduit/evolution-python) library lets you access Evolution Data Server in Python.

Answer (score 2):

### For Ubuntu 12.10 Claasic (With Gnome-Panel)

Evolution-Python module has been depreciated now. Evolution Data Server 3.6 can be accessed with Python using gobject introspection. For this, `gir1.2-edataserver-1.2` and `gir1-2-ecalendar-1.2` also need to be installed.

Refer to this answer:  **[Coding own applicaion for Gnome-shell Calendar](https://askubuntu.com/questions/193954/coding-own-applicaion-for-gnome-shell-calendar)**

It should work for panel clock-applet also.

Comment: Unity's datetime indicator also uses Evolution Data Server to list upcoming events, so this will work for the default Ubuntu  desktop as well.