# Coding own application for Gnome-shell Calendar / Evolution calendar

Tags: gnome, python, calendar

I'm looking to write a calendar application in python that will interact with `gnome-shell-calendar`. I've asked around, and I was told that it uses **[`evolution-data-sever`](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/evolution-data-server)**

To get its information, I found out that there is a `python-evolution` python module that allows you to interact with the evolution server. But, that module has now been **depreciated**. Is-there another way to interact with the sever?

I've also noticed a process called **`gnome-shell-calendar-server`**. What's The difference between that and the evolution one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Evolution Data Server 3.6 can be accessed with Python using gobject introspection.  For this, `gir1.2-edataserver-1.2` and `gir1-2-ecalendar-1.2` also need to be installed.

For example, the following script will list all the events in all calendars in evolution-data-server.

```
#! /usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from gi.repository import ECalendar
from gi.repository import EDataServer

# Open a registry and get a list of all the calendars in EDS
registry = EDataServer.SourceRegistry.new_sync(None)
sources = EDataServer.SourceRegistry.list_sources(registry, EDataServer.SOURCE_EXTENSION_CALENDAR)

# Open each calendar containing events and get a list of all objects in them
for source in sources:
    client = ECalendar.CalClient.new(source, ECalendar.CalSourceType.EVENT)
    client.open_sync(False, None)

    # ret is true or false depending if events are found or not
    # values is a list of events
    ret, values = client.get_object_list_as_comps_sync("#t", None)
    if ret:
        for value in values:
            event = value.get_as_string()
            print event
```

Comment: any hint, on how to use this in trusty? `gir1.2-ecalendar-1.2` is not available anymore.

Comment: @flx I was wondering if you made this example work without `gir1.2-ecalendar-1.2`?

Comment: @mark-tully Can you update your answer as `gir1.2-ecalendar-1.2` deprecated?

Comment: @mark-tully Can you at least answer my question?

Answer (score 1):

[Mark's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/203278/172828) was probably good in 2012, but it's now a bit outdated. I wanted to play with this and managed to do it after digging on my own.

### Packages

This was tested on Ubuntu 20.04 with the following packages installed:

```bash
sudo apt update
sudo apt install -y \
    gir1.2-ecalendar-1.2 \
    gir1.2-ecal-2.0
```

### Conda environment setup (optional)

If you use your system's python, you'll only need `pgi` pip package. Here's how to get it working with Conda:

1. I used `conda` to create my virtual env so I installed `pgi` pip package
2. I installed [`libgirepository`](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/libgirepository) and [`pygobject`](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/pygobject) using conda-forge.
3. I symlinked required typelib files from `gir1.2-ecalendar-1.2` and `gir1.2-ecal-2.0` to my conda env's `girepository`'s folder exactly like this:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

set -ex

girepository_source=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/girepository-1.0
conda_env_name=evolution-calendar-playground
conda_girespository_destination=${CONDA_PREFIX}/envs/${conda_env_name}/lib/girepository-1.0/

# setup conda environment
conda activate ${conda_env_name}
pip install pgi
conda install -c conda-forge libgirepository -y
conda install -c conda-forge pygobject -y

# compare the girepository folders
diff -rq "${girepository_source}" "${conda_girespository_destination}"

# link only required typelib files
ln -s "${girepository_source}/EDataServer-1.2.typelib" "${conda_girespository_destination}"
ln -s "${girepository_source}/Soup-2.4.typelib" "${conda_girespository_destination}"
ln -s "${girepository_source}/Camel-1.2.typelib" "${conda_girespository_destination}"
ln -s "${girepository_source}/GData-0.0.typelib" "${conda_girespository_destination}"
ln -s "${girepository_source}/Json-1.0.typelib" "${conda_girespository_destination}"
ln -s "${girepository_source}/Goa-1.0.typelib" "${conda_girespository_destination}"
ln -s "${girepository_source}/ECal-2.0.typelib" "${conda_girespository_destination}"
ln -s "${girepository_source}/ICalGLib-3.0.typelib" "${conda_girespository_destination}"

# alternative version of the above, link all files that are missing
typelibs_not_in_conda_env=$(
    diff -rq "${girepository_source}" "${conda_girespository_destination}" \
    | grep "Only in ${girepository_source}" \
    | cut -d " " -f 4-
    | tr "\n" " "
)

for typelib in $(echo ${typelibs_not_in_conda_env} | tr " " "\n"); do
    ln -s "${girepository_source}/${typelib}" "${conda_girespository_destination}"
done

# compare the girepository folders (again)
diff -rq "${girepository_source}" "${conda_girespository_destination}"
```

### Updated python example to retrieve all events from all calendars in Evolution Data Server

Here's an updated python script that uses *gobject introspection* (it's highly based on Mark's example). It does the same as before, but written differently and updated to use `gir1.2-ecal-2.0` instead of `gir1.2-ecalendar-1.2`.

I've linked some documentation to make it easier to know what's going on and added a bunch of `print` statements since these libraries are dynamically loaded and it's a bit harder to get intellicense on them. Feel free to cleanup everything once you have what you need.

Also, according to the docs, I think some of the connections I open should be cleaned and I'm not doing it, but you should :)

```python
import gi

gi.require_version('EDataServer', '1.2')
from gi.repository import EDataServer

gi.require_version('ECal', '2.0')
from gi.repository import ECal

from gi.repository import Gio

# https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/Gio-2.0/classes/Cancellable.html#Gio.Cancellable
GIO_CANCELLABLE = Gio.Cancellable.new()


class EvolutionCalendarWrapper:
    @staticmethod
    def _get_gnome_calendars():
        # https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/EDataServer-1.2/classes/SourceRegistry.html#EDataServer.SourceRegistry.new_sync
        registry = EDataServer.SourceRegistry.new_sync(GIO_CANCELLABLE)
        return EDataServer.SourceRegistry.list_sources(registry, EDataServer.SOURCE_EXTENSION_CALENDAR)

    def _get_gnome_events_from_calendar_source(self, source: EDataServer.Source):
        print(source.get_display_name())

        # https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/ECal-2.0/classes/Client.html#ECal.Client
        client = ECal.Client()

        # https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/ECal-2.0/classes/Client.html#ECal.Client.connect_sync
        new_client = client.connect_sync(
            source=source,
            source_type=ECal.ClientSourceType.EVENTS,
            wait_for_connected_seconds=1,  # this should probably be configured
            cancellable=GIO_CANCELLABLE,
        )

        if new_client:
            events = []
            # https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/ECal-2.0/classes/Client.html#ECal.Client.get_object_list_as_comps_sync
            ret, values = new_client.get_object_list_as_comps_sync(sexp="#t", cancellable=GIO_CANCELLABLE)
            if ret:
                for value in values:
                    print(value.get_status())
                    print(value.get_location())
                    print(value.get_descriptions())
                    print("due timestamp:", value.get_due().get_value().as_timet())
                    start_time_value = value.get_dtstart().get_value()
                    print("start_date", start_time_value.get_date())
                    print("start_time", start_time_value.get_time())
                    print("timestamp:", start_time_value.as_timet())
                    print("as_timet_with_zone:", start_time_value.as_timet_with_zone())
                    print("timezone:", start_time_value.get_timezone())
                    # event_str = value.get_as_string()
                    # print(event_str)
                    event = value
                    events.append(event)
        return events

    def get_all_events(self):
        calendars = self._get_gnome_calendars()
        events = []
        for source in calendars:
            events += self._get_gnome_events_from_calendar_source(source)
        return events


def main():
    evolutionCalendar = EvolutionCalendarWrapper()
    events = evolutionCalendar.get_all_events()
    for event in events:
        print(event)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Now extra caution with what you do with the events out there as you can also edit them, don't break your calendar ;)

Comment: Any way you can give an example to insert a event to a calendar this way ?

Comment: In c editing ecalcomp also edit the event in backend. Not sure how do it in python though. For example If I set date with ecomp.set_dtstart(), with it change directly without sync? I  any case it is not clear how get events only from a date range or how to insert a event ?